# CKAccountChanged notification is only received once

Tags: ios13, cloudkit

I want to receive notification in my iOS App when the iCloud account status changes, and hence I register via

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
selector: #selector(iCloudAvailabilityChanged),
name: Notification.Name.CKAccountChanged,
object: nil)

And indeed, when I background my App, and flip the iCloud switch for the App in Settings, and then go back and foreground my App, I receive the notification right after applicationWillEnterForeground.

However, if I repeat this, so background my App for a second time, flip the switch, and then foreground my App again, the notification is NOT received. And also not if I do that a third, fourth, etc. time.

This behaviour happens to me not sometimes, but always, and I have tried on different devices and it is all the same.

I use iOS 13 and Swift 5.

Is this intended behaviour, or is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide a screenshot of what you are changing when you "flip the iCloud switch for the App in Settings"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment above implies, I think you may be flipping the wrong switch. As I understand it, `CKAccountChanged` is fired when you change one of two things:

1. **Sign in/out** of iCloud on the device.
2. **Turn iCloud Drive on/off** (in `Settings > iCloud Profile > iCloud > iCloud Drive`)

I have not read anywhere that changing the iCloud availability for a specific app will fire `CKAccountChanged`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes indeed, I think I am flipping the wrong switch. When I do point 1 and 2 in your answer, I get the correct behaviour.  I had misunderstood the docs it seems, since I thought the same behaviour should be expected when I flip the " iCloud Switch for my specific App". And by that switch I mean the switch that is for my App in the long list of App-specific switches right below the iCloud Drive switch that you refer to. I just wonder what happens if the user goes and flips that App-specific switch...